# Termos para testes experimentais usando o olfato e paladar

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, expressões-equivalentes, termos

Me lembro das aulas de química orgânica que o meu professor mencionava um termo específico para testes qualitativos usando os sistemas sensoriais, mais especificamente o olfato e o paladar. Foram usados na categorização estrutural de diversos hidrocarbonetos por Emil Fischer, além de outras grandes descobertas como o LSD por Albert Hofmman.

Sei que o termo análogo em inglês é o "**taste testing**", mas ele não ajuda muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após revisar as anotações das aulas, acabei encontrando o termo, que era **Testes Organolépticos**. Esses testes dizem respeito às propriedades organolépticas das substâncias, como o odor e sabor, bem como coloração e textura. Ficou famoso com o recente incidente da alteração de sabor da água tratada de diversas cidades do Rio de Janeiro, tendo como agente responsável pelo sabor incômodo, a geosmina.

Em retrospectiva, acabei entendendo que o termo é mais apropriado para descrever a caracterização de compostos na química, justamente por abranger outros sentidos como a visão, por exemplo na identificação de coloração na forma cristalina ou em solução, bem como os outros sentidos que citei.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que os dois termos técnicos correctos em português é olfatometria e gustometria.

Para a olfatomeria há um conjunto de normas europeias e também ISO, tirado do site [IDAD](https://www.ua.pt/pt/idad/olfatometria)

- EN 13725 Teste olfatométrico
- EN 13725 Odour limiar de odor de compostos

Sobre gustometria encontrei este trabalho final de curso em medicina - [*"GUSTOMETRIA NA PRÁTICA CLÍNICA"*](https://eg.uc.pt/bitstream/10316/32087/1/Gustometria%20na%20pr%C3%A1tica%20cl%C3%ADnica-%20Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20%C3%A0%20Popula%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Portug.pdf)

Comment: Checando a referência dada, creio que "gustometria" é o termo para o teste do paladar em si, enquanto a pergunta se refere a testes químicos _usando_ o paladar como ferramenta. Não sei se, como parece ser o caso de "olfatometria", o mesmo termo tem os dois significados, mas seria preciso outra fonte para confirmar.

Comment: Oh @stafusa, a reposta às tuas objeções está clara nas referências incluidas. Se não queres ler também não precisas de inventar defeitos a uma resposta que é suficiente.

Comment: Relaxa, bad, eu li a parte que me pareceu relevante, mas se deixei de ver algo importante, que tal me indicar o lugar?

Comment: Eu acabei achando o termo. No caso meu professor usava Testes Organolépticos, que acaba sendo mais geral em relação aos sentidos usados do que testes olfatórios ou gustativos, mas que acaba fazendo sentido pois constantemente compostos químicos também são identificados pela coloração na forma cristalina, por exemplo.

Comment: @AsAves pode responder à sua própria pergunta se quiser elaborar. Seria interessante ter uma contribuição mais desenvolvida relacionando os termos entre si e definindo-os.